# AngularJS : Refreshing data in view on click of tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am a complete newbee to Angular so please excuse my ignorance!

I have a page which has three tabs (using Angular Material for tabs) which show a list of records. Each tab has to show different records though (e.g. OPEN tab has to show records having 'Open' status, CLOSED has to show records in 'Closed' status and so on):

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController as someCtrl">
<md-content>
    <md-tabs>
        <md-tab id="tab1" >
            <md-tab-label>OPEN</md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>                
                <div ng-view></div>
            </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab id="tab2" md-on-select="someCtrl.showTaskListing('Error')">
            <md-tab-label>EXCEPTIONS</md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>
                <div ng-view></div>
            </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab id="tab3" md-on-select="someCtrl.showTaskListing('Closed')">
            <md-tab-label>CLOSED</md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>
                <div ng-view></div>
            </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</md-content>
</div>
```

This is my controller (RequestSenderService is just a utility service which is used to do $http operations):

```
angular
    .module('SomeModule')
    .controller('SomeController', someController);

function SomeController($scope, $location, $http, RequestSenderService) {

    showTaskListing('Incomplete');

    function showTaskListing(status) {

        var httpResponsePromise = RequestSenderService.sendRequest("/getTasks?status=" + status);

        httpResponsePromise.then(
            function (response) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.tasks = response.data;
                            for (task in this.tasks) {
                                task.isSelected = true;
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }, 1000);
            }
        )
    }
```

This is the routing config:

```
angular.module("SomeModule",["ngRoute","ngMaterial"])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when("/tasks", {
                templateUrl : "js/tasklist/tasklist.partial.html",
                controller : "SomeController as someCtrl"
            })
            .when("/addTask", {
                templateUrl : "js/taskDetails.partial.html",
                controller : "AnotherController as anotherCtrl"
            })
            .otherwise( {
                redirectTo : "/tasks"
            })

    }) ;
```

And finally this is my template:

```
<div>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>                
            <th>Task Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">                
            <td ng-bind="task.title"></td>
            <td ng-bind="task.description"></td>
            <td ng-bind="task.type"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now when I am loading the page (/tasks) data loads fine on the first tab but it loads the same data on other two tabs as well and even though I have given `md-on-select` on each of the tabs and the function gets called allright but the data doesn't refresh on the page.

Can somebody please help? Thanks.

Comment: Why are using a timeout in the promise response handler?

Comment: Just add a console.log() after `httpResponsePromise` line and inside/After the for loop to see if your `showTaskListing` method is getting called or not, or if it is then what result are you getting. If method is not getting called, then we need to change the way the things are setup, if the results are same then it's your backend which needs change. Do and check in your browser console

Comment: @mindparse The timeout is for using $scope.apply()

Comment: @XavitojCheema The method is being called and the data coming from backend is also correct. I stripped console.logs while posting so that code is little less verbose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I just looked at an Angular material tab demo, and modified it to your needs, Here is the [link](http://codepen.io/Xavi07/pen/eZxEgY)

you just need to modify

```
$scope.selectedTab = function(index) {
    // your httpResponsePromise
}
```

it should work, just ignore the css part it just code copied from angular material demo, you just need to setup your html and js the way I have.

Basically `md-on-select` is an expression evaluated on a click and not an event handler. so you have to save `md-on-select="result = selectedTab()"` and then put `{{result}}` in your template.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Changing function to use scope made it work!

Comment: You mean calling `showTaskListing`when defined within scope vs `someCtrl.showTaskLisiting` made it work?

Comment: Yes. This is my function now: `$scope.showOpenTasks = function () {
        $location.path('/tasks');        
        showTaskListing('Open');
      }`